# When a font misses one letter with a diacritic sign (č) but has another one (š), can I make it display the missing sign?

Tags: fonts, typography, unicode

I would like to use the [Gochi Hand](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Gochi+Hand?preview.text=%C5%A1%20%C4%8D%20%CB%87%20&preview.text_type=custom) font but it misses character "č" that my language uses. However, it displays š, for example, just fine. These letters are formed by combining normal letters ("c" or "s" with a hacek/caron: "ˇ"). The font displays standalone hacek "ˇ" just fine. It does not seem to implement the [combining caron](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/030c/index.htm) unicode character. Can I somehow make the font to display č as it is supposed to?

Comment: I suppose you have to edit the font...

Comment: Ha, like this, using Fontforge, "build accented characters" and anchor points: https://fontforge.org/docs/techref/accented.html
I did not realize it was so simple:-).